# Stolen 3ds before Nintendo ID update: can I get my games back?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

Maybe this is a bit late, but is there any way to get my old purchased games back? My 3ds was stolen in 2012, and had purchased some eShop games on it. Only the 3ds itself was stolen, not the box/charger/manual.

Comment: [This thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/3DS/comments/1d9e6n/if_you_ever_get_your_3ds_stolen_heres_what_to_do/) may be helpful, but given this incident it 2 years old, you may have issues.  Either way, you should contact [Nintendo Customer Service](https://www.nintendo.com/consumer/index.jsp)

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, the only way would be to make sure the account that you have for eShop is on the new one that you have. If not, contact the support team, explain what happened, and hope for the best.